# Need to clone a existing wordpress admin page

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a new page which will have same functionality of one the page of admin.
I have a page which is accessed by **/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order**.
I have made a copy of this page by the name "new-post0.php" but when I access new cloned page , its content is different!
I m missing something at registering this new page?

Comment: This is probably a synchronistuc problem in the DCLR precompiler.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc No, I think this might be one of those problems that occurs between the keyboard and the chair. I think the acronym is USR.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't copy and paste Wordpress core files. That's called "hacking the core" which is very very bad. 
http://websynthesis.com/dont-hack-wordpress-core/

You should instead develop your "new-post" page as a new custom post type.

You can learn about them here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Answer (score 1):

The link `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order` you posted refers to a new post page for a custom post type.

To get another page like that, you'll need to create another [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and add the [custom meta fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

If you can't code it, there are plugins that you can use to achieve the same results. 
[Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to create custom post types and [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for custom fields. Right now, you should download ACF from Github.